# Strange endgroup errors and enumerate errors are everywhere

Tags: errors, equations

I am writing a document.

#### Problem with equations

After I tried to put two equations into the document, LaTeX started giving me a whole bunch of errors such as:

- `\begin{document}` ended by `\end{equation}` and
- Extra `\endgroup`.

#### Problem with margin and enumerate

As well as this, the second page of my document has the margin further left than it should be (since I should still be inside an `enumerate`) and when I try to make a new `\item` inside this `enumerate`, it doesn't even give me the number (should be 3) in the document) anymore. Has anyone got any tips?

I'm aware that it may be something really simple such as a missing curly bracket, but I cannot find errors in between my last `\begin{enumerate}` and `\end{enumerate}`. If anyone could help me out with this it would be greatly appreciated.

Below is my code (I have attempted to make the code a little shorter by saying text instead of displaying my actual text, which is significantly longer):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\title{title}

\author{my name}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
...
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
...

\section{Telecommunications Infrastructure Planning}
text here
\begin{enumerate}
\item text
\item text
\item text
\item text
\end{enumerate}

My solutions to these tasks are given below:
\\*
\newline

\begin{enumerate}
\item text    
    \item text    
    \item Below is the graph I drew:

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[height=2.5in,width=3.5in,angle=0]{pic.eps}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}

\item text
    \end{enumerate}

\section{Compound Interest}
For this part of the mixed session, the following tasks were set:
\begin{enumerate}
\item text    
    \item text
\item text    
    \item text    
    \item text
\end{enumerate}

The following was what I did to complete the above tasks:
\begin{enumerate}
\item The following was the model I created in excel:

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[height=1.125in,width=2.125in,angle=0]{pic.eps}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}

\item I then modified the model as can be seen below:

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[height=2in,width=1.75in,angle=0]{pic.eps}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}

    The above two models were developed using the compound interest equation, which is given below:


    \begin{equation*}
        \begin{center}
            $A = P(1 + \frac{r}{n})^{nt}$
        \end{center}
    \end{equation*}


where
\newline
$A$ is the total amount in the account at any given time; \newline
$P$ is the principal (initial) amount in the account; \newline
$r$ is the annual interest rate; \newline
$n$ is the number of times the interest is compounded per year; \newline
$t$ is the number of years.
\\*
\newline

The difference in these results was that at the intervals 1, 2, 3 and 4 years, which both models had in common, the second model, which compounded quarterly, had accumulated slightly more interest. This was due to it compounding quarterly instead of annually. The 5\% interest annually was 1.25\% interest quarterly.


\item As $n \to \infty$, the compound interest formula becomes:

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{center}
        $A = Pe^{rt}$
    \end{center}
\end{equation*}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please reduce your example to a [MWE (minimal working example)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/25077) which contains only the essential parts.

Comment: Don't use the figure-environment if you don't want your graphics to float. `[h!]` doesn't mean "here" but only "here if there is place and it doesn't break the rules". http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=floats

Answer (score 4):

There are two locations where you use

```
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{center}
    $ ... $
  \end{center}
\end{equation*}
```

You don't need to `center` the contents inside an `equation*`; it's done by default. Moreover, `equation*` is already in math mode, so you need only use

```
\begin{equation*}
  ...
\end{equation*}
```

---

You different margins may stem from the fact that you're using `twoside` mode.

---

Finally, even though you didn't mention this: Don't use `\\` to break a line or start a new paragraph. Rather leave empty (blank) spaces in your code.

Comment: you don't say so explicitly, but it's the `\begin{center}...\end{center}` that takes the job out of the `equation` environment and causes the mismatch of `\begin{document} ... \end{equation*}` and fouls up grouping.  only explicitly math sub-environments should be used within an `equation` environment unless they're further protected by being put inside as `\text`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is full of `\newline` and `\\*` that are wrong. If you don't like the spacing setup of the `IEEEtran` class, don't use it; if you *have* to use it for a submission, then do as they want.

Here's an edited version of your code, with some tricks. The most important fact is however fixing the wrong formula with `center` inside `equation*`.

1. The graphic file should be included with a size depending on `\columnwidth` rather than absolute dimensions
2. No `\\*` or `\newline`
3. The explanations of the variables can be given as an `itemize` environment with zero separation and empty label

Here's the code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{newtxmath} % I can't stand CM math with Times text
\usepackage{graphicx}

% the following two packages are already loaded by IEEEtran
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\title{title}

\author{my name}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
...
\end{abstract}

\section{Telecommunications Infrastructure Planning}
text here
\begin{enumerate}
\item text
\item text
\item text
\item text
\end{enumerate}

My solutions to these tasks are given below:
\begin{enumerate}
\item text  

\item text  

\item Below is the graph I drew:
  \begin{center}
  \medskip
  \includegraphics[width=.8\columnwidth]{example-image}
  \medskip
  \end{center}

\item text
\end{enumerate}

The above two models were developed using the compound interest equation, which is given below:
\begin{equation*}
A = P\biggl(1 + \frac{r}{n}\biggr)^{nt}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{itemize}[nosep,label={}]
\item $A$ is the total amount in the account at any given time;
\item $P$ is the principal (initial) amount in the account;
\item $r$ is the annual interest rate;
\item $n$ is the number of times the interest is compounded per year;
\item $t$ is the number of years.
\end{itemize}
The difference in these results was that at the intervals 1, 2, 3 and 4 years, which both models had 
in common, the second model, which compounded quarterly, had accumulated slightly more interest. This 
was due to it compounding quarterly instead of annually. The 5\% interest annually was 1.25\% interest 
quarterly.

\end{document}
```

[image]